# java menu program switch case avoiding exit if number selected out of menu

Tags: java, input, switch-statement

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter Any one number from following list to carry out Equation  ");
        System.out.println("1.Add ");
        System.out.println("2.Subtract ");
        System.out.println("3.Divide ");
        System.out.println("4.Multiply ");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int read=in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter 2 number for Equation ");
        double a=in.nextDouble();
        double b=in.nextDouble();
        double r;
        switch (read) {
            case 1 -> r = a + b;
            case 2 -> r = a - b;
            case 3 -> r = a / b;
            case 4 -> r = a * b;
            default -> {
                System.out.println("Error! Select from 1 to 4 ");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result of Equation is:  "+r);
    }

        }
```

if i select any number greater than 4 . switch case does not exit and ask 2 input from user and after input of numbers switch case exit. 
    what should i do to make switch case exit if i select number greater than 4 ?

Comment: whats the java version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence of execution is wrong if you are expecting to skip inputs for `a` and `b`
try adding a conditional if block

```
double a;
double b;
if( 0 < r && r < 5) {
  a = in.nextDouble();
  b = in.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: yes initialized double a=0; double b=0; and if (0<read && read<5) instead of "r" .  double r is for saving result. where int read is to read user input for menu.

Answer (score 0):

Initiatize the int read = 5 befor the user is making his input. Surround the part of the scanner with a while-loop and the condition (read>4 || read < 0).

Comment: i am asking for 2 inputs first when user select functions from menu then if function selected is valid than 2 more input for carry out arithmetic expressions. if i initialized read=5 i can not ask input.

Comment: My answer would loop the first scanner until the user makes an input between 0 and 4. Then the variable read is set on a right value. After this, your code is executed fine.